# Should there be an [experimental-procedure] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We already have [experimental-design](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experimental-design).  However there are **a lot** of questions that don't seem to fit that tag but would all be united by something along the lines of [experimental-procedure](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experimental-procedure).

For example:

- [When collecting cell lysates for a Western blot, how do I induce di-sulfide bonds?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1683/when-collecting-cell-lysates-for-a-western-blot-how-do-i-induce-di-sulfide-bond)
- [How long does it take to stain cells?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1690/how-long-does-it-take-to-stain-cells)
- [What temperature should mammalian B-Cells be stored at outside of the incubator?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/what-temperature-should-mammalian-b-cells-be-stored-at-outside-of-the-incubator)
- [How long can E. coli stocks be stored at -20°C?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1220/how-long-can-e-coli-stocks-be-stored-at-20c)
- [Alternatives to ethidium bromide for staining small nucleic acids?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/432/alternatives-to-ethidium-bromide-for-staining-small-nucleic-acids)
- [How long can I store extracted RNA?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/973/how-long-can-i-store-extracted-rna)
- [How can I avoid digesting protein bound DNA](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/6/how-can-i-avoid-digesting-protein-bound-dna)

I'm sure that there are many more.

Do we feel that this would be a good tag to have?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is a good idea. Not only can we then organize the questions based on specialty but also that it pertains to experiemntal procedures (or specific aspects therein).

Answer (score 1):

Since I've asked half of those questions and intent on asking more, perhaps "protocols"?

As an aside, isn't this website supposed to be an improve bio-protocols forum?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about adding a [lab-techniques](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lab-techniques) tag for those questions a while ago, but I feared that this would be too broad to be useful. I'm not sure yet if such a tag would make sense.

Answer (score -1):

What about [at-the-bench] or similar variations?

Comment: I think the issue with that is that new users are unlikely to try it as a tag leading to them missing it out entirely.  Whereas with some of the other other tags suggested the users would likely try typing `experimental` or `lab` then get the correct tag suggested to them.  I can't see anyone trying `at-the...` :)

Comment: @ Rory M, good point :)

Comment: this sort of tag is also sure to torture non-native English speakers.